# How can I remove a key from key Authentication plugin by curl?

Tags: kong

I can create a consumer and a api key successfully by the curl:

```html
$ curl -X POST http://kong:8001/consumers/ \
    --data "username=<USERNAME>" \
    --data "custom_id=<CUSTOM_ID>"
```

But I have no idea how to remove the key.

Comment: Solved, I need to learn more about RESTful.

Comment: I guess the answer was `curl -X DELETE ...`, right?

Comment: Yes, but  I couldn't find the url anywhere.  My teacher told me that how to infer a url by the thought of RESTful.  I did it.

Answer (score 0):

You can issue a DELETE request to the admin API

Specify the consumer-id and the key-auth-id you want to delete:

$ curl -X DELETE http://kong:8001/consumers/[consumer_id]/key-auth/[key-auth_id]/